# The react-router-dom doesn ' t work well and the screen turns out white

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm making few practica but when I loaded the router into my new "project" in `react-router-dom` v6 the screen turns white like I compile the router wrong.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { about } from ".//views/about.js"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/about" element={<about />} />
        <Route path="/inicio" element={<home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

This is my about.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function about() {
  return <div>Soy una pagina de practica</div>
}
```

In other forum, I've told that use the `<Switch>` method, but I used `react-router-dom` v6 and need to use `<Routes>`. So if anyone can help I'd be grateful because I tried everything nothing seems to work me.

Comment: that is a default export. you can't import it in { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper React components are Capitalized.

[Rendering a Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)

> **Note:** Always start component names with a capital letter.
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.
> For example, `<div />` represents an HTML div tag, but `<Welcome />`
> represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.
>
> To learn more about the reasoning behind this convention, please read
> [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

The `About` component is also default exported, so it needs to also be default imported (*as opposed to named exports/imports*).

```
import About from "./views/about.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/inicio" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

...

```
export default function About() {
  return <div>Soy una pagina de practica</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks sr! So how can i default import the function then? With a capital letter only? I've tried in many ways and always the screen turns white.

Comment: @Gabrielrivas Default import looks like `import About from "...."`, named import looks like `import { About } from "...."`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the App component as below:

```
import React from "react";
...
import About from "./views/about.js" // remove the curly braces as it's a default export
```